# wrong current time - php time function

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with the **time** function in PHP.

It provides a different time.

For example, the current time in my PC is 10:00AM, it appears 5 hours late..

**any thoughts?**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Is it your server that you're running the PHP on?

Comment: Perhaps your server is in another time zone? PHP is executed on the server

Comment: @11684 if that's the problem? how can i fixed it? i'm using xampp..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server system is configured with the wrong timezone for your location. Fix that with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: Is there a place this can be put so that all scripts in a web application use it?

Comment: @Marcel: Either you change it in php.ini (if you have access) and it works across all apps on the server, or else you have to call the function in a central place in your app. No magic bullet.

Answer (score 1):

can change the timezone in php ini file also
e.g.

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```